# Splitting input and result as array

Tags: java

If i have an input smt. like that:
1,10;3,3;4,1. Lets say String input.
How can I split it in ";", so the result could be like this:

```
[1,10]
[3,3]
[4,1]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `String.split(String regex)`

Comment: And you’ve tried what?

Comment: what have u tried so far ?? Have u checked String split API so a Split(";")

Comment: Arrays.stream("1,10;3,3;4,1".split(";"))
                .map(s -> s.split(","))
                .map(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        //your input is 1,10;3,3;4,1
        input = scanner.next();

        String[] splitted = input.split(";");
        //save the new list or array
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();


        for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(splitted[i]);
            //for later usage
            list.add(splitted[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing on the question says the input is coming from stdin.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar so what? input can be a value coming from elsewhere, doesn't change anything.

Comment: That's my point, no need to assume where the input is coming from, simply starting with a list of numbers is enough. Anyway, OP showed no indication that they tried anything, and the question has been closed.